# How do I deal with negative numbers in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to code a very basic Assembler language in C.
Each instruction has 32 bits, the first 8 being the Opcode and the following 24 containing an immediate value (if the instruction comes with one. Else it's just zeros).
The Opcodes are defined as simple numbers. For example `PUSHC` is defined as `1`.

Now I want to test if the Opcode and the immediate value are properly separable.

I wrote the following defintions:

```
#define SIGN_EXTEND(i) ((i) & 0x00800000 ? (i) | 0xFF000000 : (i))      // Handles negative Immediate Values (i)
#define IMMEDIATE(x) SIGN_EXTEND(x & 0x00FFFFFF)                        // Returns the Immediate Value of an instruction (x)
#define OPCODE(x) (x >> 24)                                             // Returns the Opcode of an instruction (x)
#define OP(o) ((o) << 24)                                               // An instruction with an Opcode (o)
#define OPI(o, i) (OP(o) | IMMEDIATE(i))                                // An instruction with an Opcode (o) and an Immediate Value (i)
```

In a method `void runProg(uint32_t prog[]) {...}`, I pass an Array that contains the instructions for an Assembler program, in order, separated by commas, like such:

```
uint32_t progTest[] = {OPI(PUSHC, 3), OPI(PUSHC, 4}, OP(ADD), OP(HALT)};
runProg(progTest);
```

Here's what `runProg` does:

```
void runProg(uint32_t prog[]) {
    int pc = -1;            // the program counter
    uint32_t instruction;

    do {
        pc++;
        instruction = prog[pc];
        printf("Command %d : 0x%08x -> Opcode [%d] Immediate [%d]\n",
               pc, instruction, OPCODE(instruction), IMMEDIATE(instruction));
    } while (prog[pc] != OP(HALT));

}
```

So it prints out the full command as a hexidecimal, followed by just the Opcode, followed by just the immediate value. This works for all instructions I have defined. The test program above gives this output:

```
Command 0 : 0x01000003 -> Opcode [1] Immediate [3]
Command 1 : 0x01000004 -> Opcode [1] Immediate [4]
Command 2 : 0x02000000 -> Opcode [2] Immediate [0]
Command 3 : 0x00000000 -> Opcode [0] Immediate [0]
```

**Now here's the problem:**

The command `PUSHC` only works with positive values.
Changing the immediate value of the first `PUSHC` call to `-3` produces this result:

```
Command 0 : 0xfffffffd -> Opcode [255] Immediate [-3]
Command 1 : 0x01000004 -> Opcode [1] Immediate [4]
Command 2 : 0x02000000 -> Opcode [2] Immediate [0]
Command 3 : 0x00000000 -> Opcode [0] Immediate [0]
```

So as you can see, the immediate value is displayed correctly, however the command is missing the Opcode.

Changing the definition of `IMMEDIATE(x)`
from

```
#define IMMEDIATE(x) SIGN_EXTEND(x & 0x00FFFFFF)
```

to

```
#define IMMEDIATE(x) (SIGN_EXTEND(x) & 0x00FFFFFF)
```

produces the exact opposite result, where the Opcode is correctly separated, but the immediate value is wrong:

```
Command 0 : 0x01fffffd -> Opcode [1] Immediate [16777213]
Command 1 : 0x01000004 -> Opcode [1] Immediate [4]
Command 2 : 0x02000000 -> Opcode [2] Immediate [0]
Command 3 : 0x00000000 -> Opcode [0] Immediate [0]
```

Therefore, I am relatively sure that my definition of `SIGN_EXTEND(i)` is flawed. However, I can't seem to put my finger on it.

**Any ideas on how to fix this are greatly appreciated!**

Comment: OPI clobbers the opcode  with negative immediate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x01fffffd` is correct; the 8-bit operation code field contains 0x01, and the 24-bit immediate field contains 0xfffffd, which is the 24-bit two’s complement encoding of −3. When encoding, there is no need for sign extension; the `IMMEDIATE` macro is passed a (presumably) 32-bit two’s complement value, and its job is merely to reduce it to 24 bits, not to extend it. So it merely needs to be `#define IMMEDIATE(x) ((x) & 0xffffff)`. When you want to **interpret** the immediate field, as for printing, then you need to convert from 24 bits to 32. For that, you need a different macro, the way you have different macros to encode an operation code (`OPI`) and to decode/extract/interpret the operation code (`OPCODE`).

You can interpret the immediate field with this function:

```
static int InterpretImmediate(unsigned x)
{
    //  Extract the low 24 bits.
    x &= (1u<<24) - 1;

    /*  Flip the sign bit.  If the sign bit is 0, this
        adds 2**23.  If the sign bit is 1, this subtracts 2**23.
    */
    x ^= 1u<<23;

    /*  Convert to int and subtract 2**23.  If the sign bit started as 0, this
        negates the 2**23 we added above.  If it started as 1, this results in
        a total subtraction of 2**24, which produces the two’s complement of a
        24-bit encoding.
    */
    return (int) x - (1u<<23);
}
```